# How to display images from a folder in a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to display images from a folder in a gridview whose path is stored in ms sql database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how to display different images in gridview C# .NET

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10065396/how-to-display--different-images-in-gridview.aspx

Display Images In GridView From DataBase C# VB.NET

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/display-images-gridview-from-database.html

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty common task, and Microsoft has code examples.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx