# ASP.Net Gridview with paging and images from folder

Tags: asp.net

I want to know is it a gridview control or is it done by using table??? or I know the images used in this grid are from folder. I want to develop a same thing need your help. No idea how to do it. I just know how to use gridview. Thanks and awaiting for your response.

http://www.propertyguru.com.sg/singapore-property-listing?listing_type=sale&search_type=district&property_id=&interest=&distance=1&property_type=&freetext=&districts%5B%5D=&hdb_estate=&maxprice=&maxbed=&minbed=&minsize=&searchbtn=go

Comment: That site isn't even running ASP.NET it's running on AWS/Linux http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=http://www.propertyguru.com.sg

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I want to develop a same grid in asp.net. How can i do this ?? Plz help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this.  You could use ASP.NET MVC.  If you stick with ASP.NET Web Forms you could use a GridView, a ListView, a Repeater, etc.  I'd suggest using a ListView.  It combines many of the best features of the GridView and the Repeater.

Here's a quick tutorial that walks through using a ListView to display a product listing, including images.  It doesn't look the same as your sample, but the idea is that you can style it however you want with a little HTML/CSS knowledge.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx

Here's another article that describes the ListView control and why it's probably a better fit than the GridView:

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84471/new-trends-in-aspnet-data-binding-the-listview-control/

If you decide to stick with the GridView, here's a stack overflow question about displaying images from a GridView.  There are some useful links in the answers:

[How to display images from a folder in a gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020739/how-to-display-images-from-a-folder-in-a-gridview?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

To develop the same type of grid in ASP.NET WebForms the easiest method would be to use the ListView control.  It allows you to define a template for each row, and create a pager just like the gridview.  Documentation on the listview can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790%28v=vs.100%29.aspx