# how can i display image with data to datagridview from datatable

Tags: c#

I want to load datagridview with image and data from datatable that contain my table data with image name store in image_item column

Here i have created image column instance

```
DataGridViewImageColumn imgCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
imgCol.HeaderText = "Image";
imgCol.Name = "image";
dgv_items.Columns.Add(imgCol);
```

here i get my image directory path

```
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) +@"\itemImages\";
if (Directory.Exists(appPath) == false)
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(appPath);
}
```

// here i loop through each row of datatable

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_items.Rows)
{
     if (row.Cells["item_image"].Value.ToString().Equals(""))
     {
        //if my DataTable image Column have null value show default image
        row.Cells["image"].Value = Properties.Resources.download;
     }
     else
     {
       // Here i want to display image on datagridview cell
        row.Cells["image"].Value = Bitmap.FromFile(Path.Combine(appPath, 
        row.Cells["item_image"].Value.ToString()));
      }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display images from a folder in a gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020739/how-to-display-images-from-a-folder-in-a-gridview)

Comment: You didn't tell us what is it that is not working or what is the problem you are facing?